# Representing string of length 4 in 8 character length

Tags: java, freemarker

I am working with freemarker and i have `value` variable that holds string of variable length but less than 8.

What i want to print it in 8 character spaces only.

i.e

```
${value}
```

should be spanned over 8 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want either `${value?right_pad(8)}` or `${value?left_pad(8)}`.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. I have one more doubt, to print out on a txt file i am using freemarker. Now i have a condition that if the length of string is more than 15 then it should print the rest on the next line and so on.
I have solved this problem i.e. say i have a string of length 32, then first 15 are on line 1, 16-30 on line 2 and the remaining two on line 3, but now after that i need to keep printing on the line 1 only, how do i go back to line one, since after printing this string my curson is on line 3.Thanksl

Comment: Is not there anyway i can just jump across the document. to some specific coordintates, because my frinal print has to be accoridint to a specific format.

Comment: I don't really follow what you want here, but I suppose it should be a separate stackoverflow question. Anyway, you probably need to build on `value[index]`, `value?length` and `value?substring(from[, to])`. Maybe create a `#macro` or `#function` from it for clarity and reusablity.  Some relevant documentation: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html, http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851157/repositioning-the-cursor-with-freemarker
If it makes any sense now. thanks.